# Force minted in tcolorbox package to not stylize single quotes and grave symbols

Tags: pdftex, tcolorbox, minted

I have this code with the following output:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,     
    openright,
    twoside,  
    a4paper,  
    english,  
    brazil,   
    draft
]{memoir}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\definecolor{corAzulTema}{RGB}{0,66,137}
\definecolor{corFundoCaixas}{RGB}{245,245,245}

\tcbset{
    listing engine=minted,
    minted options={fontsize=\small,linenos,numbersep=3mm,breaklines},
    colback=corFundoCaixas,
    colframe=corAzulTema!40,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    listing only,
    left=7mm,
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    drop fuzzy shadow,
    before skip=\baselineskip,
    grow to left by=13mm,grow to right by=15mm,
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[corAzulTema!40](frame.south west)rectangle([xshift=7mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
}

\newtcbinputlisting{\javaScriptCode}[3][]{%
    listing file={#3},
    title=\texttt{#2},
    colframe=corAzulTema,
    minted language=javascript
}

\DeclareTotalTCBox{\inlineJavaScriptCode}{ s v }{
    reset,
    listing only,
    on line,
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    tcbox raise base,
    boxrule=0.7pt,
    top=1mm,
    bottom=0mm,
    right=1mm,
    left=1mm,
    boxsep=0.5pt,
    before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
    colback=corFundoCaixas,
    colframe=corAzulTema,
    drop fuzzy shadow,
    arc=3pt}
{\mintinline{javascript}{#2}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item apostrophe/single quotes: \inlineJavaScriptCode{'string'}
    \item double quotes:  \inlineJavaScriptCode{"string"}
    \item grave: \inlineJavaScriptCode{`string`}
\end{enumerate}

\javaScriptCode{title}{strings.js}

\end{document}
```

[image]

JavaScript file (strings.js):

```
let s1 = 'string';    // apostrophe/single quotes
let s2 = "string";    // double quotes
let s3 = `string`;    // grave
```

My problem is when I'm using the `\inlineJavaScriptCode` command, the single quotes and the grave symbols are being stylized, but I want them rendered as they are being shown when I use the `\javaScriptCode` which reads an external file. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Easiest way, if you can run lualatex, is to comment out `fontenc` and compile with lualatex.

Comment: For `memoir` class under pdflatex, try commenting out `draft` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out `draft` in the class options.

[image: minted in non-draft mode]

What happens is that `minted` sees the `draft` option and prints without using external files and fancy features: `draft` "uses `fancyvrb` alone for all typesetting; `Pygments` is not used. This trades syntax highlighting and some other `minted` features for faster compiling." (`minted` manual, p12)

Under pdflatex, this faster method looks like it includes not blocking standard ligatures for quotes or undoing them (which makes sense, because the ligature information is stored in the font `.tfm` files).

Lualatex must have a different font mechanism (and can also use system and TTF/OTF fonts), but in any case, draft mode with lualatex does not have syntax highlighting either.

MWE

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,     
    openright,
    twoside,  
    a4paper,  
    english,  
    brazil,   
%    draft
]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\definecolor{corAzulTema}{RGB}{0,66,137}
\definecolor{corFundoCaixas}{RGB}{245,245,245}

\tcbset{
    listing engine=minted,
    minted options={fontsize=\small,linenos,numbersep=3mm,breaklines},
    colback=corFundoCaixas,
    colframe=corAzulTema!40,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    listing only,
    left=7mm,
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    drop fuzzy shadow,
    before skip=\baselineskip,
    grow to left by=13mm,grow to right by=15mm,
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[corAzulTema!40](frame.south west)rectangle([xshift=7mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
}

\newtcbinputlisting{\javaScriptCode}[3][]{%
    listing file={#3},
    title=\texttt{#2},
    colframe=corAzulTema,
    minted language=javascript
}


\DeclareTotalTCBox{\inlineJavaScriptCode}{ s v }{
    reset,
    listing only,
    on line,
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    tcbox raise base,
    boxrule=0.7pt,
    top=1mm,
    bottom=0mm,
    right=1mm,
    left=1mm,
    boxsep=0.5pt,
    before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
    colback=corFundoCaixas,
    colframe=corAzulTema,
    drop fuzzy shadow,
    arc=3pt}
{\mintinline{javascript}{#2}}%



\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item apostrophe/single quotes: \inlineJavaScriptCode{'string' `` " ` ' `` ''}
    \item double quotes:  \inlineJavaScriptCode{"string"}
    \item grave: \inlineJavaScriptCode{`string`}
    \item line \inlineJavaScriptCode{let s1 = 'string';    // apostrophe/single quotes}
\end{enumerate}

\javaScriptCode{title}{strings.js}

\mintinline{javascript}{`string`}

\end{document}
```